# Azure Media Service Audio Only

Tags: audio-streaming, azure-media-services

We have begun using the Azure Media Service (AMS) to encode, encrypt and host our videos (MP4) which is working well.  However, in addition to videos we have MP3 audio files.  Since we are already using the AMS it made sense to put them here as well however we are experiencing problems.

When we try to encode from the portal we receive an error asking us to try again later, when we encode from the Azure Media Services Explorer (AMSE) it completes the encoding but will not play from the Azure Media Player, it displays an error:

[image]

What is the best way of encoding and playing audio using AMS, we even tried encoding from AMSE using mp4 adding InsertBlackIfNoVideo from this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#silent_audio with no luck.

Would it be best for audio to just use blob storage with the Audio tag?

UPDATE:
Streaming works fine from blob storage but I have now tried encoding using AMSE with multiple presets including:

Adaptive Streaming
Content Adaptive Multiple Bitrate MP4
AAC Audio
AAC Good Quality Audio

All result in the same error shown above.

When trying to encode from the portal I receive the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my .NET app I was using audio encoding for mp3 files with Media Encoder Standard using Audio-only presets AAC Good Quality Audio and encoding worked fine (audio has been encoded and you can play it using Azure Media Player)

```
{
  "Version": 1.0,
  "Codecs": [
    {
      "Profile": "AACLC",
      "Channels": 2,
      "SamplingRate": 48000,
      "Bitrate": 192,
      "Type": "AACAudio"
    }
  ],
  "Outputs": [
    {
      "FileName": "{Basename}_AAC_{AudioBitrate}.mp4",
      "Format": {
        "Type": "MP4Format"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#aac-good-quality-audio

As I remember Azure Media Encoder didn't worked for me too with audio encoding, but Media Encoder Standard works fine in that app

Comment: I have just tried encoding with this setting and from both the Azure portal and the Azure Media Player I get the error: A network error caused the video download to fail part-way.

Comment: @user351711 I had some problems with video encoding and the issue was that my video file doesn't include some H264 tags, which was removed from Azure after their last update. When I had issue with video Azure support team helped me to solve it, they included all H264 tags to the next update. Did you try few mp3 different samples?